# Visual Studio 2010 Beta Crashes on open

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've worked with VS 2010 Beta 1 for weeks with no issue, but now it crashes on open.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled with no success.  Does anyone have any advice?

Regards.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this".

Comment: What does it say when it crashes? (Computer programs can't talk?)

Comment: A bit more information wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: Are you getting some alert and then it closes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting the follow on startup:

```
"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" on startup
```

and then it closes, please try the follow :

1. Open Regedit
2. Go to `"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\General"`
3. Set the "UILanguage" value to 0x409

it will resolve the startup crash...

Comment: While you didn't get me to solution through this, I was able to get my reinstall to work by blowing out the 10.0 registry tree.

Answer (score 3):

Use the JIT debugger to attach a copy of VS2008 to the crashing process and get a stack trace. This may lead you to the problem (which is why I've posted this as an answer). If you still don't know what it is, post the stack trace here and I'll try to let you know what the issue is.

If you don't have symbols available when viewing the stack trace, load symbols from the Microsoft Symbol Server via Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols. All of the VS2010 runtime modules I've seen have symbols available through there so the traces should be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Solution if VisualStudio is not installed within the same profile as executed:

Open the commandline in the directory of the datenv executable and try

devenv.exe /resetsettings